# Is it possible to identify the type of query (select, create etc) executed by sqlite3_step without searching select/create?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, sqlite

Is it possible to identify the query type (Definition, Manipulation, Query etc) executed by SQLite API `sqlite3_step` ?

`sqlite3_step` will return `SQLITE_DONE` if the query is successfully executed. This will be same if the query is a `CREATE TABLE` query or `SELECT * FROM <table>` query (if the `SELECT` query returns no rows).

Is it possible to identify the `CREATE` query and `SELECT` query without searching for the strings 'CREATE' and 'SELECT' ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install an [authorization callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html) so that the `sqlite3_prepare*` calls inform you what the statement will do.

Comment: i have set the call back; but couldn't find any info regarding the query type. Can u pls explain how to use it to identify query type ?

Comment: The second parameter of the callback is the action code.

Comment: below is a single create query result,        {null,18,sqlite_master,null,main,null}{null,2,student,null,main,null}{null,23,sqlite_master,type,main,null}{null,23,sqlite_master,name,main,null}{null,23,sqlite_master,tbl_name,main,null}{null,23,sqlite_master,rootpage,main,null}{null,23,sqlite_master,sql,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,ROWID,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,name,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,rootpage,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,sql,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,tbl_name,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,type,main,null}{null,20,sqlite_master,ROWID,main,null}

Comment: parameters are separated by ','

Comment: the second one is an integer that will give the operation type, that is ok .but what is the criteria i should follow to select one from the (around) 14 results (calls to call back)...

Comment: Table names beginning with `sqlite_` are internal system tables; you can ignore them. However, it is still possible to get multiple calls with a statement like `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT ...´; you should ignore READ or SELECT if there is another more specific action.